# How to get my sql result from a php file to javascript using xhr

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to get a result of an SQL request(Array) to my JavaScript using xhr 
here is my code.

```
include('../ConnectBDD.php');

$unique_entrepot = "SELECT DISTINCT entrepot FROM articles_ax";
$add = $pdo->prepare($unique_entrepot);
$verif = $add->execute();
$retour = $add->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ( $retour as $value){
  echo  $entrepot=array_values($value); //$entrepot is the value that i want to get to my javascriot file 
}
```

And my JavaScript is

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET','Requetes/get_entrepot_qr.php',false);// get_entrepot is the file that contain the sql request 
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
            if(xhr.responseText!="norecords" && xhr.responseText!="many") {
                var resultat = (xhr.responseText)
            alert(resultat);
```

Comment: so what was the problem?

Comment: use json_encode() from php side and parse the response in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. First when you echo your array on the php-side, use surrounding `<script>` tag and the php-function [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It should look like:

```
echo '<script>';
    echo 'var entrepot = '.json_encode (array_values ($value)).';';
echo '</script>';
```

That should produce this output (valid javascript)

```
<script>
    var entrepot = ["value_1", "value_2", "value_3", ...];
</script>
```

Now the variable entrepot (as an array) will be available in javascript.

Comment: may array look like this is assoc wich mak it hard to decode with javascript {"entrepot":"AS_SF"},{"entrepot":"ZSF_FG"},{"entrepot":"Z1BW-INDUS"} do u have an idea ?

Comment: this should also be no problem just set the second paramenter of `json_encode()` to be `true` to keep key -> value structure. `json_encode (array_values ($value), true)`